# Ruby regex multiple repeating captures

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to parse a subset of a webpage with regex for just fun. It was fun till I encountered with the following problem. I have a paragraph like below;

```
foo: 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.
bar: 1, 2 and 3.
```

What I am trying to do is, get the numbers in the first line of the paragraph starting with `foo:` by applying following regex:

```
foo:(?:\s(\d)(?:,|\sand|\.))+
```

This matches with the above string but it captures only the last occurrence of the capture group which is `5`.

How can I capture all the numbers in a paragraph starting with `foo:` till the first occurrence of `.` using single regex pattern.

Comment: You can't in Ruby without help of `\G` http://rubular.com/r/VKOaLEYmSI

Comment: Yeah, but no need using `\K`, [`s.scan(/(?:foo:\s*|(?!\A)\G\s*(?:,|and)?\s*)(\d+)/)`](http://rextester.com/XPWVD8530) will do. But `s[/foo:([^.]+)/,1].scan(/\d+/)` looks prettier.

Comment: Although it didn't affect Rubular way of showing results, `\K` is there for a pure representation of numbers.

Comment: That `\G` made the trick, thanks but could you please post this as an answer with the explanation of `\G` and also maybe `\K`? I already made a search and found what it does but an explanatory answer may help someone who is searching an answer for a similar problem.

Comment: Make yourself a hash: `str.scan(/\w+:.*?\./).map { |s| [s[/\w+/].to_sym,s.scan(/\d+/)]}.to_h #=> {:foo=>["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"], :bar=>["1", "2", "3"] }`

Comment: Your solution does not fit the bill. First, it returns for, not only the lines starting with `foo:` and second, I asked the question to do this with **single** regex.

Comment: Who is the owner of "Your solution"? Please begin your comments with the username of the person to whom you are addressing your comment, preceded by "@". Look at other SO questions and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think there is no ambiguity in my comments. If you read all the comments in chronological order, their targets are quite clear. But I'll keep this in mind, thanks for your advice.

Comment: @revo your regex solved my problem, thanks.

Comment: Excellent, @revo! Please post your solution as an answer, preferably with the regex presented in free-spacing mode, with each element documented (as I did in my answer). Are you sure `\K` [is needed] (http://rubular.com/r/zfNjHXL9Rl)? The doc for [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-scan) speaks to the need for `\K`: "If the pattern contains groups, each individual result is itself an array containing one entry per group." (i.e., that `\K` is not needed). The regex simulator suggests that's actually a property of `MatchData`. No?

Comment: FooBarZoo, `\K` can be read as "forget everything matched so far". The string preceding `\K` must be matched, but is not part of the match returned. Here that's all matches, but the values of the capture groups are unaffected.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks I added an answer. I said previously I used `\K` for pure representation of digits in demo only (earlier comments). However I didn't notice output for matching parts differ from output of capturing groups (in regex101 [it's different](https://regex101.com/r/bLwh8P/1)) at the very first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Repeating capturing group's data aren't stored separately in most programming languages, hence you can't refer to them individually. This is a valid reason to use `\G` anchor. `\G` causes a match to start from where previous match ended or it will match beginning of string as same as `\A`.

So we are in need of its first capability:

```
(?:foo:|\G(?!\A))\s*(\d+)\s*(?:,|and)?
```

Breakdown:

- `(?:` Start a non-capturing group

  - `foo:` Match `foo:`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!\A)` Continue match from where previous match ends
- `)` End of NCG
- `\s*` Any number of whitespace characters
- `(\d+)` Match and capture digits
- `\s*` Any number of whitespae characters
- `(?:,|and)?` Optional `,` or `and`

This regex will begin a match on meeting `foo` in input string. Then tries to find a following digit that precedes a comma or `and` (whitespaces are allowed around digits).

`\K` token will reset match. It means it will send a signal to engine to forget whatever is matched so far (but keep whatever is captured) and then leaves cursor right at that position.

I used `\K` in Rubular regex to make result set not to have matched strings but captured digits. However Rubular seems to work differently and didn't need `\K`. It's not a must at all.

Answer (score -1):

This answer uses just one regex, but admittedly does a bit of pre- and post-processing. (Please allow me a bit of fun. I do think there may be some instructional value here.)

```
str = "foo: 1, 2, 34, 4 and 5. and 6."

r = /
    \d+             # match one or more digits
    (?=[^.]+:oof\z) # match one or more digits other than a period, followed
                    # by ":oof" at the end of the string, in a positive lookahead
    /x              # free-spacing regex definition mode

str.reverse.scan(r).join(' ').reverse.split
  #=> ["1", "2", "34", "4", "5"]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
s = str.reverse
  #=> ".6 dna .5 dna 4 ,43 ,2 ,1 :oof"
a  = s.scan r
  #=> ["5", "4", "43", "2", "1"]
b  = a.join(' ')
  #=> "5 4 43 2 1"
c  = b.reverse
  #=> "1 2 34 4 5"
c.split
  #=> ["1", "2", "34", "4", "5"]
```

An empty array is returned if there is no match.

So, why all the reversing? It's to allow me to use a positive *lookahead*, which, unlike a positive *lookbehind*, permits variable-length matches.